# Java Multicast not working

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

I am writting a little network-based game in my spare time where i need a server browser. I want to do this with a multicast with Datagramsocket.

The code runs smoothly without any runtime or compilation errors but the Packages arn't sent. I tried to sniff it with WireShark. Here is the code of my sender method:

```
public void sendRequest() throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException{

    InetAddress adr = InetAddress.getByName(this.address); //Address = 239.0.0.4


    try(DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket()){

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

            String msg = "request";

            DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                    msg.getBytes(),
                    msg.getBytes().length,
                    adr,
                    this.port); //this.port == 8888


            serverSocket.send(msgPacket);


            Thread.sleep(150);


        }

        serverSocket.close();

    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.err.println("Error while trying to create DatagramSocket!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

I dont see any problems here but when i sniff it with wireshark with the following filter:

[Filter number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9lAz.png)

or with this filter:

[Filter number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNQhW.png)

I dont see any packages that i send.